# Undo Git pull without loosing previous uncomitted local files

Tags: git, github

I just made a git pull from the Master branch.

However, I lost all my local changes and files. I did NOT commit my changes. It's been a long time since I did a commit.

Is there a way to undo the most recent git pull i did WHILE NOT losing my local files (that are now gone)?

Comment: Commit regularly. don't pull without committing.  (I actually never pull so there is no chance of this, I `remote update` then merge or rebase)

Comment: Interesting approach.

I also commit all the time, however, one of my co-students did not ... he isn't used to git so he messed it all up haha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you did not commit your files before doing so there is no way to get them back, as git was not told to track their changes.

Comment: I was hoping that there were something I missed in the documentation, but sadly my hopes were too high. Thank you for your clarification, Peter.